# Trying to make my batch file process faster by using ping. now jumps out of loop

Tags: batch-file, command-line

The script below works but it slows down **alot** when hitting an offline host.

```
@echo off
rem Setup the output file. This just wipes the pre-existing file from last set of data mining
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ('time /t') do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
echo %mydate%_%mytime% > output\datamine.txt
**setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in (hosts.txt) do (
psexec \\\%%a findstr /I ":" "C:\ProgramData\Firewall\event.log" >> output\datamine.txt )
endlocal**
```

*I rewrote with a ping statement, intending to skip over non-answering hosts. Here's the meat of it:*

```
for /f %%a in (hosts.txt) do (<br>
ping -n 1 -w 100 %%a | for /f "skip=1 tokens=3 delims= " %%b in ('findstr bytes') do (set COMPNAME=%%b)
if errorlevel 1 goto FAIL
psexec \\%%a findstr /I ":" "C:\ProgramData\Firewall\event.log" >> output\datamine.txt )
goto END
:FAIL
echo host not answering
:END
endlocal
```

The problem is obvious in that I am exiting the do loop when a host fails to answer ping. I need the script to see errorlevel 1 and just skip to the next host. Not sure where I should end the loop. Also, I am not too sure of my choice of "goto" lines.
Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exiting out of your for loop. Instead of doing the goto add an else and move the parenthesis after it.

Here is a function I wrote to do this and how to implement it.

```
for /f %%a in (hosts.txt) do (
   call :IsPingable %%a && (
   psexec \\%%a findstr /I ":" "C:\ProgramData\Firewall\event.log" >> output\datamine.txt 
   ) || (
     echo host %%a not answering
   )
)   
exit /b

:IsPingable comp
ping -n 1 -w 3000 -4 -l 8 "%~1" | Find "TTL=">nul
exit /b
```

Comment: That's it. Much better. I'm not sure why I didn't think of the call. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

example code:

```
for /f %%a in (hosts.txt) do ping -n 1 "%%a">nul && call :success "%%a"|| call :fail "%%a"
goto:eof

:success
echo success: %~1
goto:eof

:fail
echo fail: %~1
goto:eof
```